# Change point detection

Tags: r

I'm trying to find change points of multiple data using for loop.
In the for loop, each data needs to be typed their own ncpts value(which is 3 in the codes below).
So, I want to know how to get the vector or list of possible ncpts given in the error message which I can use in the for loop.
The codes below are just for checking.

```
library(changepoint)
set.seed(1)
x=c(rnorm(50,0,1),rnorm(50,5,3),rnorm(50,10,2))
out=cpt.meanvar(x, pen.value=c(2*log(length(x)),100*log(length(x))),penalty="CROPS",method="PELT")
cpts.full(out) #range of segmentations
pen.value.full(out)
plot(out,diagnostic =TRUE)
plot(out, ylab='Data', ncpts=3)
```

> Error in .local(x, ...) :
> Your input object doesn't have a segmentation with the requested number of changepoints.
> Possible ncpts are: 15,11,9,7,5,2,1,0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grabbing the error message using `try`. Using `gsub` with regular expressions we extract everything after `"Possible ncpts are: "` and split the values at the comma. After further cleaning with `gsub` we are able to coerce `as.numeric`.

```
r <- try(plot(out, ylab='Data', ncpts=3), silent=T)
s <- strsplit(gsub(".*Possible ncpts are: (.*)", "\\1", attr(r, "condition")), ",")
res <- as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", el(s)))
res
# [1] 15 11  9  7  5  2  1  0
```

Comment: Thanks, It helped a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

It has been some time since the question was posted. Here is another perspective to solve this problem.

```r
set.seed(1)
x <- c(rnorm(50, 0, 1), rnorm(50, 5, 3), rnorm(50, 10, 2))
result <- fastcpd::fastcpd.meanvariance(x)
result@cp_set
# [1]  50 100
plot(result)
```

[image: plot]

Disclaimer: I am the developer of the R package `fastcpd`.